# Trigger code if rows are found, if nothing returned do nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have code which I have already tested and used in the past. I want to automate this code now with an if-statement. Meaning when rows are returned I want to execute the process with the cursor. If no records are found or nothing is returned I don't anything to happen and simply stop.

Attached, is my code how can I embed the if statement correctly?

```
declare @date smalldatetime 
set @date = (select max(date) from inventory_table) 



select symbol, id, count(distinct 2) cnt into #target 
from inventory_table 
where date between dateadd(day, -7, @date) and @date
group by symbol,id 
having count(distinct 2) >= 4 


-- Process with cursor starts here
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (iid int)
INSERT INTO @MyList 
select distinct id from #target


DECLARE @iid int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT iid FROM @MyList
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @iid   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 

    declare @mindate date,
    @maxdate date

    set @mindate = ( select min(date) from inventory_table where ID = @iid  )
    set @maxdate =  ( select max(date) from inventory_table where ID = @iid   )

      exec spReissuingIDs @mindate , @maxdate, @iid

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @iid   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: You may check `@@rowcount` system variable just after DML statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I would at least give some thought to reworking your stored procedure to deal with sets so you don't have to a cursor at all.

Comment: Also how could `COUNT(DISTINCT 2)` ever be anything other than `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some slight modifications, you can handle your requested need, eliminate the use of a CURSOR, and do a little optimizing.

```
-- Define @MyList --
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (
    ListId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Iid INT,
    MinDate DATETIME,
    MaxDate DATETIME
);

-- Fetch Data --
INSERT INTO @MyList (
    Iid, MinDate, MaxDate
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.id, i.MinDate, i.MaxDate
FROM #target AS t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MIN( [date] ) AS MinDate, MAX( [date] ) AS MaxDate FROM inventory_table WHERE id = t.id 
) AS i;

DECLARE @ListId INT, @iid INT, @min DATETIME, @max DATETIME;

-- Set @ListId to 1 for the first row.
SET @ListId = 1; 

-- While @ListId <= to the number of rows in @MyList, run spReissuingIDs for each Iid --
-- Note: If no rows are present, spReissuingIDs will never be called --
WHILE ( @ListId <= ( SELECT MAX( ListId ) FROM @MyList ) )
BEGIN

    -- Current Row --
    SELECT
        @iid = Iid, @min = MinDate, @max = MaxDate
    FROM @MyList WHERE ListId = @ListId;

    -- Process Row --
    EXEC spReissuingIDs @min, @max, @iid

    -- Next Row --
    SET @ListId = ( @ListId + 1 );

END
```

**A few notes:**

- Using CURSORs is always a bad idea.
- Processing RBAR (row by agonizing row) is a costly idea and to be avoided if possible.

As for this example, having @MyList.ListId set to IDENTITY(1,1) assigns a unique, sequential id to each row, thereby affording you to cut the cost to using a CURSOR. I've used this a lot when I've had no other alternative to process data as a SET.

**EDIT:**

Also, as just a side note, I'm not sure where `#target` is created, but, if #target having data is the deciding factor if the code should continue, you could short-circuit this code by adding the following at the very top of the call:

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM #target )
    RETURN;
```